# pandas reindexing multiindex not working properly

Tags: python, pandas

I have a `pandas` (**version 1.0.5**) `DataFrame` with a `MultiIndex` of two levels, f.i. like:

```
mi = pd.MultiIndex.from_product((('a', 'c'), (5, 12)))
np.random.seed(123)
df = pd.DataFrame(data=np.random.rand(4, 2), index=mi, columns=['x', 'y'])
```

I want to `reindex` the **first level** of the MultiIndex to contain the keys `['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']`. Missing values should be filled with `np.nan`.

For a **non-multiindex** dataframe, I'd simply reindex with `df.reindex(index=['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'])`.
Now **with the `MultiIndex`**, I assumed that this should work (I also tried all other combinations of the arguments `labels`, `axis` and `index`):

```
df.reindex(index=['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'], level=0)
```

But instead it seems to completely ignore the `reindex` method and returns the unaltered dataframe:

```
             x         y
a 5   0.696469  0.286139
  12  0.226851  0.551315
c 5   0.719469  0.423106
  12  0.980764  0.684830
```

The only way I can reindex the MultiIndex, is by **fully generating a new `MultiIndex`**:

```
df.reindex(index=pd.MultiIndex.from_product((
    ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'], df.index.get_level_values(1).unique())))
```

---

Imho there must be an easier way to do it, otherwise I don't see any use in the argument `level` of the `reindex` method. Furthermore I quite often have several index levels, which makes reindexing extremely cumbersome.

Did I miss anything? **Any idea how to reindex *directly* without having to explicitly generate a new multiindex?**

Answer (score 4):

This behaviour is not expected. Passing the `level` argument to `reindex` on a `MultiIndex` appears to be broken still in `pandas` version 1.2.3. There is an issue on github covering this:

https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/25460